# Contao Backend Styling / layout missing

Tags: contao

Hi contao developer out there, 
Anybody knows why the styling of the whole admin backend's missing. 
I attach a screenshot, let me know if anyone knows something. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mk2mJ.png)

Comment: I have resolved the the problem. The fact is the generated styling is missing and needed to replace. but, still the backend is messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. 
The fact that, the problem comes from the server configuration. 
The Php process wasn't have enough permission, so it takes me some time to realise and knowing that I need to change the apache modul version to cgi/fpm mode.

This grants the php to recreate and generate the assets including js/css in asset folder. (at least from my own observation) and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have installled your Contao into a sub directory and setup your base url incorrect.
Have a look into `system/config/pathconfig.php` and verify the path is the same as in your browser (i.e. `return '';` for an installation in the root dir and `return '/some-dir';` for an installation in an subdir).

You should also check with web-developer tools as to which URLs for the Backend CSS it tries to load. Usually this already points out what in the base url is wrong.

Last thing, you might have set up some "strange" rewrite rules in your `.htaccess` file which may cause these problems.

Comment: So, this is what I have on my pathconfig : 
<?php

// Relative path to the installation
return '';

But, however just to let you know, I host the website at web.someweb.com (for example) but I manage the dns that has the website accessible from anotherweb.com 

So, but however I still able access the frontend and it works perfect. only the administrator backend page that messed up. 

The complain comes several day after the server has an php version update issue (not sure if it affected the backend) but the frontend is just fine.